# External HDD loses and regains connection. Windows 7 wd

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, connection

i have a western digital external hard drive that every day or so, loses and regains connection right away. I can tell this, because of that window prompt that comes up on windows every time you plug in a external hard drive or a memory card.
The drive work perfectly otherwise, but i must mention that when connected to another usb port, it seems to start up, and shut off within 5 seconds, it makes a sound as if the a power cable was unplugged.
I've checked the drive a couple of times with different tools, and there's apparently nothing wrong with it. But, it's either the drive or windows, so i'm not sure.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Drive: WD3200ME http://support.wdc.com/product/install.asp?groupid=203&lang=en

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the cable is dodgy, first thing I would suggest is a new cable.

Comment: Nah, it's not the cable, i've tried that already. This thing has never even been moved, it's not like i carry it everywhere. Just weird.